# React state in render is unavailable inside return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have these methods that do some fetching, and then once done, they set the state. But the render is called before the state is done and does not update.

The below seems to work on it's own, but takes a minute to finish.

```
     //returns an promise with Array
    getTopIDs(url) {
        return fetch(url).then(blob => blob.json()).then(json => json)
    }

     // makes a URL fetchs JSON and return promise with single ID
    getStory(id) { 
        let url = `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json?print=pretty`
        return fetch(url).then(blob => blob.json()).then(json => json)
    }

   // call above methods, set state when done
    componentDidMount() { //
        let arr = []
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let data = this.getTopIDs("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty").then((idArr) => {
                idArr.forEach((id, index) => {
                    this.getStory(id).then(res => {
                        arr.push(res)
                    })
                })
        //resolve once all pushed to arr
                resolve(arr)
            })
        })
    // set state once array is completed
        promise.then(res => {
            return this.setState({data: arr})
        })
    }
```

Then in the render below it logs 'no', 'no' and stops. Trying it outside the return it logs 'no','yes'. Searching other posts for this I tried setting a boolean when done and using the state callback but those did not work (full disclosure: I don't really understand the setState callback option)

```
render() {
        return (
        <div>
            {
                this.state.data.length
                    ? console.log('yes')
                    : console.log('no')
            }
        </div>)
    }
```

I need render to handle `this.state.data` only when done. How can I do it?

Add fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/drumgod/e2atysu3/6/

Answer (score 0):

Your method `this.getStory()` is async but your handling of the array creation is sync inside your promise.

You need to either use `async/await` or only run your `resolve(arr)` after `idArr.forEach()` is for sure completed (which may be easier to do using `Promise.all(idArr.map(...))` where the `...` is returning the result from `this.getStory()`).

Comment: I tried to implement your idea but it is super slow. The following returns only 30 results and takes 2+ secs. jsfiddle.net/drumgod/hu9qpts4/1 Can U look and see how I can optimize it? It's unusable as it is

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'll want to set your state inside `getStory`:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  data: [...prevState.data, res]
}))
```

As mentioned in the comments, this would render the component for each data point in the `forEach`.

In order to avoid this issue, this is how `componentDidMount()` should be formatted:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const arr = [];
  this.getTopIDs("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty").then((idArr) => {
    idArr.forEach((id, index) => this.getStory(id).then(res => arr.push(res)));
    this.setState(prevState => ({ data: [...prevState.data, arr] }))
  })
}
```

This also lets you get rid of the `promise.then` call at the end.

Comment: this is perfectly valid as long as OP understands this will re-render every time a result is pulled down.  So if it's a list of 100 items you will re-render the entire list 100 times

Comment: @Deryck correct. I'm updating my answer to adjust accordingly.

Comment: your answer has the same flaw as OP.  you need to use `Promise.all(idArr.map(id => this.getStory(id))).then(res => res)` or something similar to avoid race condition inside `.forEach`

Comment: @fspy I tried this out. The content does not render. Please look https://jsfiddle.net/drumgod/hu9qpts4/16/

Comment: I checked and it looks like I made a mistake on `setState`. For your example to work you'd have to look for `this.state.data[0]`, then you'd have the stories available. Keep in mind this renders every time you fetch a story.